# Java conventions for calling non-static methods from the main() method

Tags: java, conventions

I have been programming in Java for quite some time now but it was always just Android apps which don't start with a static main method. I want to know the conventions for "standard" Java programs because most of the time, I'm calling non-static methods which obviously can't directly be done through the main() method.

Here is an example program that I wrote (just printing a Fibonacci number). Is this an acceptable solution?

```java
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainClass().mainProgram();
  }

  public void mainProgram() {
    System.out.println(fibonacci(10).toString());
    // go on with the program
  }

  // suppose this method needed to be non-static
  public Integer fibonacci(int count) {
    if (count <= 0) {
      return null;
    }
    if (count == 1 || count == 2) {
      return 1;
    }
    // noinspection
    // (suppresses logically impossible null-pointer exception warnings)
    return fibonacci(count - 2) + fibonacci(count - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `mainProgram` I often pick `executeFibonacci` or such. Instead of a nullable `Integer` better use [**`OptionalInt`**] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html). Or throw a `new IllegalArgumentException()`

Comment: But this is supposed to be the method that runs the entire programme. The best solution so far is to name it "run()".

Comment: I agree to some extent. But `run` is already a method of interface `Runnable`, so I generally use `execute`. For classes that could be used from an other main class, say providing args, I would become more specific: `class FibonacciRunner` for instance. `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` indeed already specifies `Main-Class: ...`

Comment: It depends greatly on what your program does.  I added more info in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's exactly how.

Create an object instance. Call the methods on the instance.

For example, this is a typical code in a Springboot application.

An instance of `SpringApplication` is created and then the instance method `run` is invoked.

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final SpringApplication application = 
            new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

As for the name of the "main" method, in the example above `run` makes sense because you want to `run` the application.

But it could be anything like `run`, `execute`, `start`, `serve`, `scan` it depends on what your program does.

In your specific case I would call it `calculateFibonacci`, or if your class was named Fibonnacci then just `calculate()`

---

> *Is this how you would do it or what should I change?*

I think your code looks good.

The way **I** would've written would be as follows

```
public class Fibonacci {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Fibonacci fibonacci = new Fibonacci();
       fibonacci.execute();
   }

   public void execute(){
       System.out.println(fibonacci(10));
   }

   public int fibonacci(int n){

       if (n <= 0){
           throw new IllegalArgumentException(
              "n must be greater then 0. Received: " + n);
       }

       if (n == 1 || n == 2){
           return 1;
       }

       return fibonacci(n - 2) + fibonacci(n - 1);
    }
}
```

The reason for the exception instead of null it to indicate that's an actual invalid (or illegal) argument. The program can't calculate, whereas `null` would indicate the computation for a negative number results in `null` which is not the case.

But the way you have it is completely fine.